# creating a function with indexes after calling it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently stuck with this function that I need to make. I was just wondering if anyone can help me 
put an index to the 4 lines everytime I call the functions. Here is where I'm at at the momemnt and I am not getting right indexes. Any hints will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
import random

def open_box(num_items):
    num_items = 4

    print('Opening loot box:')  

    for item in range(4):
        items = item + 1
        item = random.randint(0, 100)


        if item <= 5:
            print('  Item 1 of 4... Legendary Item')


        elif item <= 15:
            print('  Item 2 of 4... Epic Item')


        elif item <= 35:
            print('  Item 3 of 4... Rare Item')


        elif item <= 100:
            print('  Item 4 of 4... Common Item')
```

Comment: Please explain a little more in what you are trying to do.

Comment: your question is vague. I do not understand what you want to do. and please edit your question, two first lines of the code is not formatted correctly.

Comment: HI there. Sorry if it a bit unclear. I am trying to make a function that has a single parameter which is num_items which is an integer specifying how many items are in the box.Now a loot box contains 4 items so a specified value of 4 is needed when calling it. This 4 items are random items with its own range/probabilities out of 100 Legendary Item = 5% or 1-5 range in1-100 Epic Item = 10% or 6-15 range in 1-100 Rare Item = 35% or 16-50 in range 1-100 and Common Item = 50% or 51-100 in range 1-100. then I need to return the list to the main program to keep track of this Items.

Answer (score 0):

You mean setting an index for every new loop or an index for each kind of loot box you get?

```
print('Opening loot box:')  
import random


for i, item in enumerate(range(4)):
    items = item + 1
    item = random.randint(0, 100)

    print(f'{i}:', end='')
    if item <= 5:
        print('  Item 1 of 4... Legendary Item')


    elif item <= 15:
        print('  Item 2 of 4... Epic Item')


    elif item <= 35:
        print('  Item 3 of 4... Rare Item')


    elif item <= 100:
        print('  Item 4 of 4... Common Item')
```

>>>

```
Opening loot box:
0: Item 4 of 4... Common Item
1: Item 2 of 4... Epic Item
2: Item 4 of 4... Common Item
3: Item 4 of 4... Common Item
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. As you see when you ran it the Item no repeats itself. I am after some hints to correct this. So when I ran it it will always have an item number 1-4. Thanks

Comment: I guess what you want to say is that you dont want to get the same item more than once?

Comment: I am actually trying to get 4 random items using a probability table

Comment: Probability table is Legendary = 5% Epic is 10% Rare is 35% and Common is 50%. And I want it to run so the output will have "Item # of 4 is (random). thanks